# Area 51 Discussion Zone Not Found page image Not Found

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, 404-not-found

This is what I see in the [Area 51 Discussion Zone 404 Page Not Found](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/1) page:

> [image]

The image is not found. Be it intentional or not, the correct address for the image is http://cdn.sstatic.net/area51/img/scanline-area51.jpg (without `/Sites`).

Comment: ***META***! :-D